# Get networkx filtered nodes from subgraph_view of filtered edges

Tags: networkx

I've created a subgraph_view by applying a filter to edges. When I call `nodes()` on the subgraph it still shows me all nodes, even if none of the edges use them. I need to get a list of only nodes that are still part of the subgraph.

```
G = nx.path_graph(6)
G[2][3]["cross_me"] = False
G[3][4]["cross_me"] = False
def filter_edge(n1, n2):
    return G[n1][n2].get("cross_me", True)
view = nx.subgraph_view(G, filter_edge=filter_edge)
# node 3 is no longer used by any edges in the subgraph
view.edges()
```

This produces

```
EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2), (4, 5)])
```

as expected. However, when I run `view.nodes()` I get

```
NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

What I expect to see is

```
NodeView((0, 1, 2, 4, 5))
```

This seems odd. Is there some way to extract only the nodes used by the subgraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion stems from the definition of 'graph.'  A disconnected node is still a part of a graph.  In fact, you could have a [graph with no edges at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#:%7E:text=The%20graph%20with%20only%20one,known%20as%20an%20edgeless%20graph.).  So the behavior of `subgraph_view()` is counterintuitive but correct.

If, however, you still want to achieve what you're describing, there are lots of potential ways, depending on your tolerance for modifying the original graph.  I'll mention two that attempt to stay as close to your current method as possible and avoid [deleting edges or nodes](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#removing-elements-from-a-graph) from `G`.

### Method 1

The easiest way using your `view` object is to take it as input to [`edge_subgraph()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edge_subgraph.html#networkx.Graph.edge_subgraph) (which only takes edges as input) like this:

```
final_view = view.edge_subgraph(view.edges())
final_view.nodes()
```

gives

```
NodeView((0, 1, 2, 4, 5))
```

### Method 2

To me, Method 1 seems clunky and confusing by defining an intermediate view.  If instead we go back up a little bit and start with `G`, we could define a `filter_node` function that checks the edge attributes of each node and filters that node if

1. all edges are flagged for removal, or
2. the node has no edges in the first place.

You could also do this by manually flagging the node itself, as you've done with the edges.

```
G = nx.path_graph(6)
G[2][3]["cross_me"] = False
G[3][4]["cross_me"] = False
def filter_edge(n1, n2):
    return G[n1][n2].get("cross_me", True)
def filter_node(n):
    return sum([i[2].get("cross_me", True) for i in G.edges(n, data=True)])
view = nx.subgraph_view(G, filter_node=filter_node, filter_edge=filter_edge)

view.nodes()
```

also gives the expected

```
NodeView((0, 1, 2, 4, 5))
```